# Sheets formula to find the sum upto the current month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to find the sum of cells starting from the month of dec 2019 to selected month (dropdown). I have tried with sumif formula.

I have tried with, but I am looking for a sum upto the choosen month.

```
=SUMIFS($B$6:$Y6, $B1:$B, ">=" & DATE(2019,12,1), $B$1:$B, "<=" & DATE(2020,11,30))
```

[Here is my worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xOPQd6o1mGm9_uWHqoow6mwdwTjLbBf_YkVd_PLxE0o/copy)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to sum row 6 or the whole columns B,D,F when starting from the month of dec 2019 to selected month (dropdown) in 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is:

- Take a fragment of your table that is interesting for us,
- Transpose it to have dates in one column and values in second column
- Query sum through this range according to date criteria taken from the sheet.

Try this formula

```
=index(query(transpose({$B$1:$1;$B$6:$6}),"select sum(Col2) 
where Col1 <= date '"&text(B15,"YYYY-MM-dd")&"' and 
Col1 >= date '"&text(A15,"YYYY-MM-dd")&"'")
,2)
```

[image]

My file is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xlSf6C52QJldpep2jXsOuPB08qYbl40wQZPip6Y_J64/copy

What I found most difficult is data validation and making a dropdown list. Your list used text values and I could not convert "Feb" value into date. On the other hand when I tried to build dropdown list from the range (first row) I could not format it properly and it was showing me 01/01/2019 type of format. It could be solved if you make somewhere on a side additional range with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is

> Sheets formula to find the sum upto the current month

Your formula though (as well as your screen-shoot) do NOT match either the title or your presented results.

#### Sheets formula to find the sum, *up to the CURRENT MONTH*

You can use

```
=SUMIFS($B$6:$6, $B$1:$1, ">"&EOMONTH(A11,-1), 
                 $B$1:$1, "<="&EOMONTH(JOIN("/",MONTH(B11&1),YEAR(TODAY())),-1))
```

[image]

*(Values in `D10` shift from your results because there is a miscalculation in yours)*

#### Sheets formula to find the sum, *up to a MONTH in ANY YEAR*

If you want to calculate **not for the current year but any year**, I suggest you create a second dropdown with years and use the following formula

```
=SUMIFS($B$6:$6, $B$1:$1, ">"&EOMONTH(A11,-1), 
                 $B$1:$1, "<="&EOMONTH(JOIN("/",MONTH(B11&1),C11),0))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)
- [`EOMONTH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093044)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [`MONTH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052)
- [`YEAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061)
- [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)